# Checkbox should be checked when pressing enter after Textbox edit in Datagrid

Tags: wpf, mvvm, datagrid, checkbox

i have datagrid with checkbox and a text box in a row.
when the value is text box is modified and pressed Enter the checkbox should be be checked based on whether the value is modified.
please tel me how can i do this?
i dont have code behind files.

Answer (score 0):

```
   <DataGrid...ItemsSource={Binding ViewModel.YourRowItems
 ...some column
   <TextBox Text="{Binding SomeText}"...

 ....some column
   <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked="{Binding IsSomeProp}"..
```

in the ViewModel, when SomeText property is changed, flip/update IsSomeProp, which will update IsChecked through binding

```
public string SomeText
{
   get {return _someText;}
   set
   {
       if (_someText != value ..
       {
           _someText = value;

           if(value != _originalSomeText)
              IsSomeProp = true;//this of course will raise prop changed for IsSomeProp
           RaisePropertyChanged( ()=> SomeText);
       }
    }
```

...anyway that's the gist